# Embedded Python in C++ DialogBoxes created by Tkinter

Tags: c++, python, mfc, tkinter, python-embedding

i have successfully embedded python into my c++ application, which runs mfc and is compiled in visual studio 2010.

Python Version I have embedded is: 
2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

I even have several methods which let me call selected functions of my main program in scripts which I load.

The problem arises when I try to create Dialog boxes using my python script using Tkinter. While these dialog boxes are displayed, the program chrashes when I try to initiliaze Tkinter and the Python Interpreter again. I could not find much information on this problem only this:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-July/114106.html

and a potential solution: http://www.python.org/workshops/1995-12/papers/ahlstrom1.html

I am new to programming with mfc and python, so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you